# Creating Cell Links with Smartsheet API Python SDK

Tags: python-3.10, smartsheet-api

I'm trying to create cell links between two sheets using Smartsheet API Python SDK, but I'm receiving the following error:

> {"response": {"statusCode": 400, "reason": "Bad Request", "content": {"errorCode": 5262, "message": "Unable to create the requested cell link(s). The source data is no longer accessible.", "refId": "amtr23"}}}

I'm the owner of one sheet, an admin of the other (also tested the owner/owner scenario with the same result). Also, I can create this link manually using Smartsheet interface (the standard way).

Below is the essential part of the code. Does anyone know what is the reason for this error and how I can address this issue?

Thank you in advance for any help or suggestion!

```py
row = Row()
row._id_ = Number(sheetA_row_id)
cells = TypedList(Cell)
cell = Cell()
explicitnull = ExplicitNull()
cell._value = explicitnull
cell._column_id = Number(A_column_id)
celllink = CellLink()
celllink._column_id = Number(B_column_id)
celllink._row_id = Number(sheetB_row_id)
celllink._sheet_id = Number(sheetB_id)
_celllink = TypedObject(CellLink)
_celllink.value = celllink
cell._link_in_from_cell = _celllink
cells.insert(0, cell)
row._cells = cells

row_update = smartsheet.sheets.Sheets.update_rows(sheets, sheetA_id, row)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code snippet uses the Smartsheet Python SDK to update a cell in Sheet A with a value that's linked in from a cell in Sheet B. As long as the owner of the specified access token has at least viewer access to Sheet B and at least editor access to Sheet A then this code should run without error.

```
# Specify access token
os.environ['SMARTSHEET_ACCESS_TOKEN'] = 'INSERT_YOUR_TOKEN_HERE'

# Initialize client. 
# Uses the API token in the environment variable SMARTSHEET_ACCESS_TOKEN.
smartsheet_client = smartsheet.Smartsheet()

# establish IDs for sheet A (the "link to" sheet)
sheetA_id = 3932034054809476
sheetA_row_id = 1304206756210564
sheetA_column_id = 5228827298293636

# establish IDs for sheet B (the "link from" sheet)
sheetB_id = 1303196942526340
sheetB_row_id = 1724835021973380
sheetB_column_id = 3838793372985220

# Build cell link
celllink = smartsheet.models.CellLink()
celllink.sheet_id = sheetB_id
celllink.row_id = sheetB_row_id
celllink.column_id = sheetB_column_id

# Build new cell for Sheet A (with cell link)
new_cell = smartsheet.models.Cell()
new_cell.column_id = sheetA_column_id
new_cell.value = smartsheet.models.ExplicitNull()
new_cell.link_in_from_cell = celllink

# Build the row to update in Sheet A
row_to_update = smartsheet.models.Row()
row_to_update.id = sheetA_row_id
row_to_update.cells.append(new_cell)

# Update row in Sheet A (add cell link to previously specified cell)
result = smartsheet_client.Sheets.update_rows(sheetA_id, [row_to_update])
```